# Return type IList<T> vs. List<T>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand this case.

Let's say I want to have a method which has a return type of `List<T>`.

```
public List<T> GetAllItems(string category)
{ ... }
```

I've been advised to use instead this header :

```
public IList<T> GetAllItems(string category)
{ ... }
```

Why so?

I've made some research and one answer could be flexibility meaning that the type could be changed if it's implementing the same interface. But the motivation had to do something with exposing the interface only to prevent changes (?), I didn't really understand it. So, again, why is it better to return `IList` instead of `List`?

Comment: It is good practice to expose objects with minimum detail needed. IList is more a abstract than List

Comment: Maybe you should go further and return `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>`? All depends on what you're using the results for and do you need the collection be ready for updates from outside the method.

Comment: @Alireza, the result is `IList`, if I'm using `.ToList()` isn't the same thing? What have I protected with less detail exposing, then?

Comment: There is one case where you might want to use a `List<T>`: If you have done some timings and determined that accessing the list isn't fast enough. Indexing an IList is around 4 times slower than indexing a List, even if the underlying collection really IS a List.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Do you have a source for that benchmark?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I cannot post my test program here now, because this thread is closed unfortunately. I'll see if I can find where I previously posted it. I just retested just now, and it's definitely true.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Really? I'm quite surprised, why is the difference so big even if the underlying type is a `List<T>`?

Comment: @VasileMarianFălămaș If your program depends on an interface it is much better than if it depends on a concrete class regardless of the fact that the concrete class has identical method/properties as the interface. Actually what you expose from a method is important not the underlying object type.

Comment: @ppetrov Yes it is surprising - I'll make a question about it so we can get some discussion.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Good idea! I'd really like to know the why about this, this made me curious ;)

Comment: @ppetrov Ok, no need, someone already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854959/why-does-casting-listt-into-ilistt-result-in-reduced-performance Check the actual answer, because there's a lot of distracting debate about how the testing was performed. I think my testing was accurate and avoided JIT effects etc, and I saw it being a little over 4x slower using an IList.

Comment: @MatthewWatson interesting answers, and now that I've read it it seems quite obvious, a good thing to know about when writing applications managing big lists